# More name parsing outliers

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation, pcre2

Names can be so difficult to parse into first, middle, last, suffix

[This group of names](https://regex101.com/r/fhH8ow/3) (saved at regex.com) is giving me a migraine.

The desired parse is actually /[^(.*)(\b[Vv][ao]n\b\s\w+|\b[Dd][eu]\s\b\w+)(.*)](https://regex101.com/r/rO8ffW/1)/ which groups 'De La', but I want to make sure that 'La name' is also included and grouped properly so I focused on the difference between 'De La name' and 'La name' to make sure the logic works.

Also not sure how to incorporate (De La \w+)|(La \w+) into the rest of the regex.

TIA

** Update (per @lemon's request) **

The name string `Emile La Sére` should return `(Emile) (La Sére)` without losing the diacritical on the "e"

`Justin De Witt Bowersock` should return `(Justin) (De Witt) (Bowersock)`

`Monica De La Cruz` should return `(Monica) (De La Cruz)`

`Robert M. La Follette` should return `(Robert M.) (La Follette)` or ideally `(Robert) (M.) (La Follette)`

`Henry St. John` should return `(Henry) (St. John)`

`Edward St. Loe Livermore` should return `(Edward) (St. Loe) (Livermore)`

`Oscar L. Auf der Heide` should return `(Oscar) (L.) (Auf der Heide)`

I've been able to successfully parse these in various groupings. I don't know if it is possible to parse the whole range in a single pattern.

The main pattern that partially works is `(^.*)\b([Vv][ao]n\s\w+|[Dd][ue]\s\w+|[Dd]e\s[Ll]a\s\w+|St\.\s\w+)\s*(.*)` however, the crossover between `De Witt`, `[Dd]e [Ll]a Cruz` and '[Ll]a Follette' is giving me a headache.

Also I am a novice regex wizard so there's that.

** Update 2 **
This [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/RYAcg0/1) from @The fourth bird is almost perfect. I dressed it up with a couple of additions to catch the previously unmentioned outliers so it's almost airtight. (Assuming there are not other pattern outliers I've missed)

** Update **

Thanks to @The fourth bird [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/1qGCQ4/1) is the one that works.

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected matches to be ultimately found and returned?

Comment: Nice. A lot closer to what I am trying to get, but "de la cruz" is coming back as "de la", "cruz". If that worked, this pattern is near perfect. I feel as though some more outliers are waiting in the wings if this works.

Comment: So "De La Name(s)" should always be in 1 group, and never just "De La" in a separate group?

Comment: That's correct. "De la name" is the entire surname.

Comment: Also can I assume if it works in pcre2 it will work in ECMAScript?

Comment: @KenIngram No, you can not assume that because those are not the same engines. But perhaps we can create the pattern in a way that it will work in both engines. Perhaps this would be a bit better (pcre) https://regex101.com/r/m5Gh82/1 Using the unicode flag and ECMEScript selected: https://regex101.com/r/eBRJwc/1

Comment: This works in pcre/pcre2 but not in my JS code https://regex101.com/r/sqQc7V/1. The 'De La' is dailing for 'De name', 'La name' and 'De La name'.

Comment: @KenIngram No, for that you would have to use the other link that I have added later on to the comment https://regex101.com/r/eBRJwc/1 and you would have to use the unicode flag `/u`

Comment: Pretty difficult to understand some of the pieces. Seems I have some study time for Saturday.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255386/discussion-between-ken-ingram-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: What do you mean by `The 'De La' is dailing for 'De name', 'La name' and 'De La name'` Are there matches that are not correct?

Comment: It worked the way you presented it, adding the unicode flag. And accounting for lowercase 'L'.

Comment: That word was supposed to be "failing' not "dailing". Anywho. You gave me the pattern that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already pointed out, names can be really difficult to parse. See a nice read about [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

For the provided example data, you might use:

```
^(.*?)\b((?:[Vv][ao]n|(?:[Dd][eu]\s+)?La|[Dd][eu]|St\.|Auf\s+der)\s+\p{L}+)(.*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match any character as few as possible
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

    - `[Vv][ao]n` Match one of `V` `v`,  `a` `o` and then `n`
    - `|` Or
    - `(?:[Dd][eu]\s+)?La` Optionally match `D` `d`, `e` `u` and 1+ whitespace chars followed by `La`
    - `|` Or
    - `[Dd][eu]` Match one of `D` `d`, `e` `u`
    - `|` Or
    - `St\.` Match `St.`
    - `|` Or
    - `Auf\s+der` Match `Auf der` with 1+ whitespace chars in between
  - `)` Close the non capture group
  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\p{L}+` Match 1+ times any letter
- `)` Close group 2
- `(.*)` Capture **group 3**, optionally capture any character

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eBRJwc/1).

When using JavaScript including the `\u` flag for [Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Unicode_character_class_escape):

```
const regex = /^(.*?)\b((?:[Vv][ao]n|(?:[Dd][eu]\s+)?La|[Dd][eu]|St\.|Auf\s+der)\s+\p{L}+)(.*)/gmu;
```

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

When using pcre for example, you might replace `\s` with `\h` to match horizontal whitespace chars (no newlines), see this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4u3arh/1).

Comment: Great lesson. Thank. This is really helping me step up my game.